# Job/Task Processing in SQL

Tags: sql-server, jobs, service-broker

I have an existing database that handles several asynchronous processes using SQL agent jobs. This has now grown to a point where using agent jobs is no longer a viable option.

I need to re-architect this so that it's more robust and scalable. Any "process" has a finite number of steps within it. In some cases, I only want to run one at a time, i.e. at any point, there could only be one instance of Process1-Step2 running, to reduce contention, and other processes can run freely as they don't cause any issues.

I am having trouble with fleshing this out initially, and was hoping someone could give me a push in the right direction. I thought I would start off with Service Broker, but that becomes slightly complex when you want to pause/halt some tasks, depending on others.

Comment: Just an idea, but something I did in the past: why don't you define some kind of configuration table, which stores jobs, their dependencies and the time when to start. Then define a procedure, which reads from this table and - if the current time matches the planned execution time and the dependencies are fullfilled - executes the planned procedure / SSIS package / whatever. Finally define an agent job, which runs every minute every day and executes this one procedure. However, if it comes to job steps or SSIS there are DB Tables available, where you can check if a certain step is running.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using agent jobs as they become a bit of a pain to manage. The current setup has an agent job for each sub process. This allows many threads to be executed at once. There is a "queue" that a procedure running all day reads from, and it starts the agent job which then runs the next step in the process. I like the concept of having parallel execution of tasks, but it's way too cumbersome and not easy to scale.

Comment: Thats why I tried to change the "an agent job for each sub process" to ONE agent job and move the executition handling to a DB procedure. ;-) You still can have parallel executions - but your procedure has to take care of it instead of the job agent.